# OpenCV: Fundamental matrix and moving camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters, reprojection-error

I have a calibrated (intrinsic parameters) camera. I take stereo photos from the objects and use them  in re-projection process to find some 3-D information of the objects.

To do that, first I calculated Fundamental matrix. Then, I get Essential matrix and from there, I have Rotation matrix and Translation vector and the other needed information.

The problem is, with different parameters, I get very different results. I know that Fundamental matrix could be different for a same stereo image but, I expect to have a same Rotation matrix and Translation vectors. However, every different parameter (e.g. number of matched features), lead to different matrices. Do I miss some thing? Am I right that the same stereo image should provide a (pretty )same Rotation, Translation and re-projection matrices?

here is my code. any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Mat img_1 = imread( "images/box01-edited.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
Mat img_2 = imread( "images/box02-edited.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );


if( !img_1.data || !img_2.data )
{ return -1; }

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 1000;
SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
extractor.compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
extractor.compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors with a brute force matcher
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L1, true);
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );

//-- Draw matches
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2, matches, img_matches );
//-- Show detected matches
namedWindow( "Matches", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
imshow("Matches", img_matches );
waitKey(0);


//-- Step 4: calculate Fundamental Matrix
vector<Point2f>imgpts1,imgpts2;
for( unsigned int i = 0; i<matches.size(); i++ )
{
// queryIdx is the "left" image
imgpts1.push_back(keypoints_1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
// trainIdx is the "right" image
imgpts2.push_back(keypoints_2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}
Mat F =  findFundamentalMat  (imgpts1, imgpts2, FM_RANSAC, 0.1, 0.99);


//-- Step 5: calculate Essential Matrix

double data[] = {1189.46 , 0.0, 805.49, 
                0.0, 1191.78, 597.44,
                0.0, 0.0, 1.0};//Camera Matrix
Mat K(3, 3, CV_64F, data);
Mat_<double> E = K.t() * F * K; //according to HZ (9.12)

//-- Step 6: calculate Rotation Matrix and Translation Vector
Matx34d P;
Matx34d P1;
//decompose E to P' , HZ (9.19)
SVD svd(E,SVD::MODIFY_A);
Mat svd_u = svd.u;
Mat svd_vt = svd.vt;
Mat svd_w = svd.w;
Matx33d W(0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);//HZ 9.13
Mat_<double> R = svd_u * Mat(W) * svd_vt; //HZ 9.19
Mat_<double> t = svd_u.col(2); //u3

if (!CheckCoherentRotation (R)) {
std::cout<<"resulting rotation is not coherent\n";
P1 = 0;
return 0;
}

P1 = Matx34d(R(0,0),R(0,1),R(0,2),t(0),
             R(1,0),R(1,1),R(1,2),t(1),
             R(2,0),R(2,1),R(2,2),t(2));

//-- Step 7: Reprojection Matrix and rectification data
Mat R1, R2, P1_, P2_, Q;
Rect validRoi[2];
double dist[] = { -0.03432, 0.05332, -0.00347, 0.00106, 0.00000};
Mat D(1, 5, CV_64F, dist);

stereoRectify(K, D, K, D, img_1.size(), R, t, R1, R2, P1_, P2_, Q, CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 1, img_1.size(),  &validRoi[0], &validRoi[1] );
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to refine your fundamental matrix calculation with a standard 8-point algorithm after you eliminate the outlying feature matches with RANSAC algortihm.

Following text is taken from calib3d documentaion for the findFundamentalMat function. **status** is an optional output parameter to determine outliers in your dataset.

> **status** – Output array of N elements, every element of which is set to 0 for outliers and to 1 for the other points. The array is computed only in the RANSAC and LMedS methods. For other methods, it is set to all 1’s.

You can then use only inlying matches with CV_FM_8POINT option to obtain more reliable fundamental matrix.